# Is it possible convert such code to vector data

Tags: web

is it possible to convert such code (probably json) into vector data. Maybe something for me help?
URL: https://eismoinfo.lt/eismoinfo-backend/layer-dynamic-features/?lks=true

Example code:

```
"[{"layer":"EAL","name":"Eismo apribojimai (laikini)","features":[{"id":"MJ:3444744","name":"Kelio remontas","details":true,"icon":"57","points":[{"min":4,"max":99,"point":[375976.0,6195836.0]}],"restrictions":[{"id":"TR:1075865","icon":"76","iconValue":50.0,"lines":{"paths":[[[375976,6195836],[376161,6195801],[376225,6195788],[376297,6195773],[376339,6195765],[376363,6195761],[376385,6195758],[376403,6195758],[376418,6195760],[376443,6195765],[376563,6195792],[376662,6195814],[376778,6195840],[376810,6195846],[376921,6195872],[376965,6195881],[376980,6195883],[376993,6195884],[377010,6195882],[377029,6195878],[377092,6195862],[377140,6195849],[377160,6195842],[377172,6195836],[377183,6195827],[377192,6195819],[377209,6195798],[377258,6195738],[377298,6195690],[377312,6195675],[377320,6195667],[377331,6195660],[377345,6195653],[377365,6195645],[377392,6195635],[377535,6195580],[377699,6195517],[377821,6195470],[377993,6195406],[378011,6195399],[378028,6195391],[378044,6195383],[378060,6195373],[378076,6195362],[378090,6195351],[378129,6195320],[378206,6195257],[378275,6195203],[378385,6195115],[378494,6195027],[378601,6194943],[378720,6194846],[378750,6194820],[378784,6194790],[378808,6194767],[378832,6194744],[378850,6194724],[378873,6194697],[378894,6194671],[378916,6194642],[378947,6194597],[379009,6194509],[379085,6194398],[379147,6194310],[379216,6194211],[379266,6194139],[379350,6194020],[379384,6193971],[379447,6193878],[379476,6193838],[379523,6193770],[379561,6193714],[379610,6193642],[379683,6193538],[379746,6193447],[379812,6193353],[379923,6193194],[379998,6193088],[380076,6192977],[380155,6192865],[380217,6192777],[380268,6192703],[380289,6192675],[380300,6192660],[380308,6192652],[380317,6192644],[380329,6192637],[380344,6192629],[380375,6192609],[380441,6192570],[380512,6192532],[380543,6192514],[380575,6192496],[380592,6192484],[380614,6192469],[380633,6192454],[380649,6192439],[380670,6192418],[380688,6192398],[380707,6192375],[380729,6192343],[380770,6192288],[380846,6192183],[380918,6192085],[380975,6192007],[381015,6191953],[381072,6191875],[381091,6191849],[381111,6191824],[381130,6191802],[381148,6191781],[381170,6191758],[381188,6191741],[381207,6191722],[381241,6191695],[381290,6191653],[381338,6191612],[381349,6191603]]]}},{"id":"TR:1075866","icon":"77","iconValue":3.0,"lines":{"paths":[[[375976,6195836],[376161,6195801],[376225,6195788],[376297,6195773],[376339,6195765],[376363,6195761],[376385,6195758],[376403,6195758],[376418,6195760],[376443,6195765],[376563,6195792],[376662,6195814],[376778,6195840],[376810,6195846],[376921,6195872],[376965,6195881],[376980,6195883],[376993,6195884],[377010,6195882],[377029,6195878],[377092,6195862],[377140,6195849],[377160,6195842],[377172,6195836],[377183,6195827],[377192,6195819],[377209,6195798],[377258,6195738],[377298,6195690],[377312,6195675],[377320,6195667],[377331,6195660],[377345,6195653],[377365,6195645],[377392,6195635],[377535,6195580],[377699,6195517],[377821,6195470],[377993,6195406],[378011,6195399],[378028,6195391],[378044,6195383],[378060,6195373],[378076,6195362],[378090,6195351],[378129,6195320],[378206,6195257],[378275,6195203],[378385,6195115],[378494,6195027],[378601,6194943],[378720,6194846],[378750,6194820],[378784,6194790],[378808,6194767],[378832,6194744],[378850,6194724],[378873,6194697],[378894,6194671],[378916,6194642],[378947,6194597],[379009,6194509],[379085,6194398],[379147,6194310],[379216,6194211],[379266,6194139],[379350,6194020],[379384,6193971],[379447,6193878],[379476,6193838],[379523,6193770],[379561,6193714],[379610,6193642],[379683,6193538],[379746,6193447],[379812,6193353],[379923,6193194],[379998,6193088],[380076,6192977],[380155,6192865],[380217,6192777],[380268,6192703],[380289,6192675],[380300,6192660],[380308,6192652],[380317,6192644],[380329,6192637],[380344,6192629],[380375,6192609],[380441,6192570],[380512,6192532],[380543,6192514],[380575,6192496],[380592,6192484],[380614,6192469],[380633,6192454],[380649,6192439],[380670,6192418],[380688,6192398],[380707,6192375],[380729,6192343],[380770,6192288],[380846,6192183],[380918,6192085],[380975,6192007],[381015,6191953],[381072,6191875],[381091,6191849],[381111,6191824],[381130,6191802],[381148,6191781],[381170,6191758],[381188,6191741],[381207,6191722],[381241,6191695],[381290,6191653],[381338,6191612],[381349,6191603]]]}}],"detours":[]},{"id":"MJ:3445148","name":"Kelio remontas","details":true,"icon":"57","points":[{"min":4,"max":99,"point":[539005.0,6002136.0]}],"restrictions":[{"id":"TR:1076225","icon":"76","iconValue":50.0,"lines":{"paths":[[[539005,6002136],[539006,6002129],[539014,6002096],[539020,6002063],[539025,6002038],[539029,6002014],[539035,6001983],[539041,6001951],[539048,6001917],[539052,6001888],[539058,6001859],[539065,6001827],[539071,6001796],[539076,6001777],[539081,6001760],[539086,6001747],[539093,6001730],[539107,6001702],[539123,6001673],[539140,6001641],[539155,6001613],[539167,6001590],[539180,6001565],[539188,6001547],[539195,6001533],[539207,6001502],[539213,6001487],[539220,6001468],[539222,6001462],[539226,6001453],[539232,6001442],[539237,6001435],[539242,6001430],[539249,6001425],[539261,6001416],[539279,6001408],[539316,6001393],[539358,6001376],[539372,6001369],[539381,6001364],[539389,6001359],[539398,6001353],[539408,6001341],[539430,6001316],[539451,6001291],[539457,6001286],[539468,6001276],[539487,6001261],[539499,6001251],[539520,6001238],[539547,6001221],[539591,6001199],[539621,6001182],[539636,6001171],[539648,6001161],[539658,6001152],[539666,6001143],[539680,6001126],[539701,6001101],[539727,6001066],[539754,6001030],[539783,6000994],[539807,6000963],[539834,6000929],[539846,6000913],[539855,6000900],[539862,6000890],[539869,6000878],[539875,6000865],[539882,6000851],[539892,6000826],[539898,6000811],[539905,6000795],[539911,6000778],[539916,6000765],[539930,6000728],[539932,6000725],[539937,6000712],[539945,6000694],[539959,6000655],[539968,6000632],[539974,6000618],[539982,6000605],[539992,6000588],[540001,6000573],[540010,6000560],[540024,6000540],[540045,6000510],[540057,6000492],[540065,6000479],[540067,6000476],[540085,6000450],[540087,6000448],[540102,6000424],[540114,6000400],[540123,6000382],[540132,6000359],[540144,6000327],[540161,6000290],[540170,6000271],[540182,6000248],[540201,6000215],[540222,6000180],[540243,6000147],[540259,6000121],[540265,6000112],[540285,6000080],[540304,6000048],[540314,6000031],[540321,6000015],[540329,5999998],[540339,5999968],[540360,5999899],[540382,5999824],[540399,5999768],[540408,5999731],[540417,5999694],[540436,5999603],[540451,5999529],[540457,5999502],[540461,5999486],[540464,5999476],[540467,5999468],[540469,5999462],[540471,5999456],[540474,5999450],[540478,5999443],[540486,5999429],[540497,5999413],[540519,5999382],[540560,5999326],[540592,5999282],[540602,5999270],[540608,5999262],[540613,5999257],[540618,5999251],[540625,5999246],[540633,5999239],[540671,5999213],[540716,5999185],[540742,5999168],[540753,5999160],[540761,5999154],[540767,5999147],[540776,5999139],[540785,5999127],[540795,5999115],[540832,5999064],[540840,5999053],[540863,5999021],[540896,5998976],[540928,5998933],[540935,5998925],[540942,5998919],[540948,5998913],[540954,5998907],[540963,5998900],[540971,5998893],[540983,5998886],[541017,5998865],[541037,5998853],[541047,5998847],[541059,5998840],[541068,5998833],[541075,5998828],[541081,5998822],[541088,5998815],[541093,5998809],[541097,5998803],[541101,5998797],[541106,5998788],[541109,5998781],[541113,5998771],[541117,5998760],[541123,5998743],[541128,5998723],[541141,5998680],[541153,5998630],[541168,5998571],[541172,5998555],[541176,5998541],[541179,5998530],[541183,5998517],[541187,5998509],[541190,5998502],[541195,5998493],[541201,5998482],[541207,5998473],[541212,5998466],[541224,5998451],[541246,5998425],[541292,5998374],[541332,5998330],[541386,5998272],[541446,5998207],[541482,5998166],[541526,5998117],[541547,5998092],[541561,5998074],[541568,5998066],[541576,5998055],[541585,5998044],[541591,5998034],[541597,5998025],[541604,5998014],[541629,5997970],[541633,5997964],[541637,5997955],[541640,5997947],[541643,5997939],[541659,5997889],[541673,5997841],[541692,5997775],[541701,5997741],[541716,5997688],[541727,5997650],[541741,5997598],[541748,5997566],[541752,5997544],[541754,5997528],[541758,5997489],[541760,5997465],[541764,5997409],[541775,5997306],[541778,5997278],[541780,5997258],[541786,5997212],[541792,5997155],[541797,5997117],[541798,5997106],[541801,5997096],[541802,5997090],[541804,5997086],[541804,5997084],[541806,5997080],[541810,5997072],[541815,5997064],[541821,5997055],[541826,5997047],[541836,5997036],[541867,5997000],[541908,5996958],[541933,5996936],[541962,5996911],[541969,5996904],[541979,5996894],[541987,5996886],[541996,5996876],[542015,5996852],[542038,5996824],[542062,5996792],[542116,5996723],[542193,5996627],[542195,5996625],[542228,5996583],[542235,5996573],[542240,5996567],[542244,5996560],[542248,5996554],[542250,5996548],[542254,5996541],[542256,5996534],[542258,5996530],[542261,5996524],[542265,5996515],[542269,5996507],[542276,5996497],[542282,5996488],[542290,5996478],[542300,5996465],[542304,5996459],[542312,5996451],[542334,5996426],[542345,5996415],[542348,5996411],[542349,5996409],[542352,5996405],[542357,5996399],[542366,5996385],[542370,5996378],[542373,5996373],[542374,5996368],[542376,5996362],[542376,5996356],[542376,5996350],[542376,5996342],[542374,5996333],[542372,5996324],[542365,5996301],[542359,5996281],[542358,5996274],[542357,5996267],[542356,5996261],[542356,5996252],[542356,5996244],[542357,5996234],[542358,5996225],[542359,5996216],[542363,5996195],[542368,5996174],[542379,5996128],[542392,5996078],[542399,5996049],[542431,5995932],[542453,5995845],[542475,5995759],[542497,5995674],[542518,5995591],[542530,5995544],[542539,5995511],[542560,5995428],[542582,5995346],[542607,5995250],[542630,5995158],[542653,5995068],[542667,5995020],[542670,5995010],[542674,5995000],[542679,5994987],[542696,5994948],[542712,5994911],[542725,5994883],[542734,5994862],[542746,5994837],[542761,5994811],[542780,5994786],[542802,5994763],[542828,5994741],[542862,5994717],[542878,5994705],[542921,5994672],[542942,5994659],[542996,5994623],[543039,5994596],[543046,5994591],[543066,5994578],[543100,5994557],[543128,5994536],[543150,5994519],[543175,5994496],[543205,5994462],[543229,5994435],[543252,5994413],[543266,5994398],[543277,5994384],[543283,5994375],[543299,5994349],[543309,5994330],[543322,5994293],[543339,5994247],[543350,5994215],[543360,5994188],[543373,5994158],[543387,5994131],[543399,5994115],[543419,5994084],[543433,5994060],[543443,5994040],[543448,5994018],[543448,5993993],[543448,5993976],[543446,5993961],[543435,5993913],[543430,5993886],[543427,5993864],[543425,5993844],[543423,5993812],[543422,5993758],[543420,5993698],[543421,5993685],[543422,5993678],[543423,5993672],[543428,5993661],[543433,5993651],[543444,5993638],[543460,5993623],[543478,5993610],[543523,5993579],[543560,5993555],[543579,5993542],[543598,5993526],[543611,5993513],[543628,5993494],[543654,5993463],[543688,5993423],[543719,5993388],[543732,5993372],[543751,5993351],[543772,5993325],[543792,5993301],[543809,5993278],[543845,5993223],[543859,5993201],[543871,5993177],[543880,5993154],[543891,5993117],[543899,5993090],[543904,5993065],[543904,5993058],[543904,5993052],[543904,5993042],[543901,5993029],[543895,5993012],[543873,5992964],[543857,5992928],[543849,5992907],[543842,5992885],[543839,5992876],[543826,5992831],[543819,5992810],[543817,5992806]]]}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Is there any additional information from the data provider to understand which format this is (most probably from an established GIS server). There's an Open Data section in the main page, that might provide some hints

Comment: If you look at the https://www.geoportal.lt/arcgis/rest/services/geoportal_public/background_Lietuva_3346/MapServer/ page, CRS is EPSG:3346 (LKS94 / Lithuania TM).

Answer (score 2):

The JSON you show is already vector data. It just is in a coordinate system that is not specified and also it's not GeoJSON formatted.

You'll have to transform it somehow to GeoJSON (using JavaScript probably) and then figure out the coordinate system the data is in.

Comment: thank you for putting me on the right track, but how can it be easily converted to a geojson file?